# FPGAとGPUの処理速度においてどちらが優れていますか？

Tags: gpu, fpga

大規模(あるいは小規模)な画像処理や機械学習、人工知能を実装するとしたら、GPUとFPGAどちらが優秀ですか？
超高性能FPGAでもGPUには処理速度の面では勝てないように個人的には考えています。パイプライン化が困難な事やハードである故の物理的な遅れがあると思うので。
皆さんはどう思いますか？ぜひ皆様のご意見が聞きたいです。

Comment: 「優秀」を判断する基準と制約条件を明らかにしてください。また、パイプライン化はFPGAを最適化する手段として一般的だと思いますが「困難」と思われる理由は何でしょうか。

Comment: 例えば、opencvの顔認識を行うじゃないですか。そのさいにGPU、FPGAのどちらで実装した方が最速なのかと聞きたかったのです。

Answer (score 5):

ケースバイケースです。

まず、CPU に性能の低いものから高いものまであるように、FPGA や GPU にもバリエーションがあります。また、FPGA はプログラマブルな回路を作るためのものである一方、GPU は画像用の演算をするためのものであり、(GPGPU はできるものの) 目的が異なります。更には、それぞれのハードウェアを動かすためのソースコードをどのように作るのかという部分にもバリエーションがあります。

このため、問題設定や実際のシステム設計に応じて「どちらが速いのか」は変わりえます。つまり、そもそも今回のご質問の前提が広すぎます。

FPGA と GPU の速度比較は論文にもなっていて、 https://scholar.google.co.jp で "FPGA GPU" をキーワードに調べるといくつか調査結果がヒットします。たとえば少し古い結果ですが、Asano, S., Maruyama, T., Yamaguchi, Y. "Performance comparison of FPGA, GPU and CPU in image processing" (2009) では、問題によって FPGA が速くなったり GPU が速くなったりしています。また、FPGA と GPU を組み合わせて使う研究もあります。

最後に、これらとは別視点の指摘として、FPGA で GPU を作る試みがあるため、二者は完全に分けられるわけではない、というものもあります。たとえば https://github.com/jbush001/NyuziProcessor は FPGA 上で GPGPU をするプロジェクトです。

Answer (score 0):

FPGA は、任意の計算回路をプログラマブルに実装できる電子回路です。GPU であってもFPGA上に実装は可能だと思っています。GPU を再現してから、その上で実行されるアルゴリズムに応じて、電子回路レベルでチューニングをかければ (既存の) GPU より高速になることは可能でしょう。

問題は、そこまでするのか、という話に集約するかと思います。機械学習において、 gpgpu 的アーキテクチャを想定した計算アルゴリズム (deep learningとか) より本格的に優位になるような、計算アルゴリズムを自分はまだ知らないですし、そういうものは存在する可能性は大いにあるけれども、まだ研究段階なのではないか、と思っています。